# ylabel style when axis y line=right

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, pgfplots, tikz-styles

When I'm using `axis y line=right`, it appears `ylabel style` is not applied, as illustrated by this MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\Large
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ylabel={Y label},ylabel style={font=\tiny}]
\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ylabel={Y label},ylabel style={font=\tiny},axis y line=right]
\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Whereas the `ylabel style` for the left plot is indeed `{font=\tiny}`, this style is not applied for the `axis y line=right` case.

Is this by design, or is this a bug?  How do I apply a `ylabel style` when I have `axis y line=right`?

---

Excerpt from `pdflatex`'s logfile:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012) (format=pdflatex 2013.4.4)

(...)

Package: pgfplots 2013/03/17 v1.8 Data Visualization (1.8-3-gaf58a29)
```

Comment: This happens because `axis y line=right` overwrites `ylabel style`. If you swap the options around (`axis y line=right,ylabel style={font=\tiny}`) you get the expected result.

Comment: Aha.  I see now that it also appears to have the side effect of adding an arrow tip and changing the tick position.

Comment: To avoid that, you can use `axis y line*=right`.

Comment: I see.  The documentation, *The starred versions (...) only affect the axis lines, without correcting the positions of axis labels*, confused me; I thought not affecting the positions of axis labels would mean that the y line would move to the right, but the ylabel would remain on the left; which would be silly (but who knows why someone might want that), but that's not what it does

Comment: @Jake An answer, please, to push this question out of the unanswered list.

Comment: @egreg: fatto... (I hope that's the correct translation, and not some insult)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because `axis y line=right` overwrites the `ylabel` style. If you swap the options around (`axis y line=right,ylabel style={font=\tiny}`) you get the expected result.

Comment: Yes, “fatto” applies correctly. `;-)`