# pgfplots ybar issue

Tags: pgfplots

I'm having trouble with pgfplots using ybar.
When I try:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=4.5cm, width=8cm, ybar, axis x line=bottom, axis y line=left, grid=none, ytick={0,10,20}, xmin=0, xmax=7, xtick={1,...,6}, x axis line style=-]
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(1,16) (2,18) (3,23) (4,13) (5,16) (6,14)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get this:

[image]

Which isn't what I wanted, since 4 should have a height of 13.

Trying this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=4.5cm, width=8cm, ybar, axis x line=bottom, axis y line=left, grid=none, ytick={0,10,20}, xmin=0, xmax=7, xtick={1,...,6}, x axis line style=-]
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(1,16) (2,18) (3,23) (4,13) (5,16) (6,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Gives this:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? How come I can't get the bars to be the correct heights?

Comment: The backtick is for inline code, you can indent lines with four whitespace characters to mark as a block code. Also your plot is correct. 4 has the ymin value of 13. try decreasing ymin value

Comment: removing ` axis y line=left,` seems to fix it

Comment: Seems like a bug? I can reproduce the undesired behaviour using `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar]
\addplot+ plot coordinates {(1,16) (2,18) (3,23) (4,13) (5,16) (6,14)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include the `ymin` en `ymax` it works. Don't know why though.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[height=4.5cm, width=8cm, ybar, axis x line=bottom, axis y line=left, grid=none, ytick={0,10,20}, ymin=0, ymax=25, xmin=0, xmax=7, xtick={1,...,6}, x axis line style=-]
        \addplot+[ybar] coordinates {(1,16) (2,18) (3,23) (4,13) (5,16) (6,14)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the answer. In fact, `ymin=0` would be sufficient... in the original post, pgfplots computed the lower axis limit to be 13.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative this solution found is to use  `axis y line*=left` instead of `axis y line=left` since the latter modifies the y label style. Please see this link [ylabel style when axis y line=right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124604/34618)

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=4.5cm, width=8cm, ybar, axis x line=bottom, axis y line*=left,grid=none, ytick={0,10,20}, xmin=0, xmax=7, xtick={1,...,6}, x axis line style=-]
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(1,16) (2,18) (3,23) (4,13) (5,16) (6,14)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

x axis line = none

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=4.5cm, width=8cm, ybar, axis x line=none, axis y line*=left,grid=none, ytick={0,10,20}, xmin=0, xmax=7, xtick={1,...,6}, x axis line style=-]
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(1,16) (2,18) (3,23) (4,13) (5,16) (6,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

x axis line = top

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=4.5cm, width=8cm, ybar, axis x line=top, axis y line*=left,grid=none, ytick={0,10,20}, xmin=0, xmax=7, xtick={1,...,6}, x axis line style=-]
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(1,16) (2,18) (3,23) (4,13) (5,16) (6,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

x axis line = bottom

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=4.5cm, width=8cm, ybar, axis x line=bottom, axis y line*=left,grid=none, ytick={0,10,20}, xmin=0, xmax=7, xtick={1,...,6}, x axis line style=-]
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(1,16) (2,18) (3,23) (4,13) (5,16) (6,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```